# Installing Software In Win XP Guest Machine on Ubuntu Host Machine?

Tags: virtualbox, virtual-machine, virtualization

I have installed Windows XP SP2 as guest OS on Lunux Ubuntu 10.10 as host os using Virtualbox. There are following issues with it:

1- I can see guest xp machine on network in host, but not able to access it. How to do it?
2- I wish to perform copy operation from host and paste operation in guest os. How to do it?

Are both the above operations possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Shared clipboard: (Shared copy-paste)**

1. Open virtualbox GUI
2. Select the VM (don't load) then click Settings in the menu
3. Under the General tab, select Advanced
4. In the "Shared Clipboard:" field, select Bidirectional

Note: For this to work, guest additions must be installed. The guest additions version must also match the virtualbox version.

You may want to share a folder between the host and guest machine so that you may "pass" an installer for Windows downloaded form the host to the OS and vice versa.

**Sharing files between the guest and the host operating system:**

From the command line:

```
VBoxManage sharedfolder add "VM name" --name "sharename" --hostpath "directory"
```

1. where VM name is what you named the virtual machine (not the OS),
2. sharename is what you want to name the shared folder directory is the
3. path to the folder in the host machine

From the GUI:

```
Open virtualbox GUI
Select the VM then Click Settings
Go to the Shared Folders tab
On the upper right corner, click the folder with the plus sign
In the Folder Path: field click the down arrow then "others..." and locate the folder
Type the folder name
Check Auto-mount
```